# Firebase - Automatically sign out user onDisconnect

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Since I have noticed that once a user signs in with email and password, on reopening the application the session will not have expired and there is no need for a new authentication, I wish to avoid this.

I want to automatically `.signOut()` a user when `.onDisconnect` is triggered. How can I achieve this? I have tried with the following code, but unsuccessfully:

```
firebase.auth().onDisconnect().signOut();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "onDisconnect", I'm assuming that you mean Realtime Database onDisconnect triggers.

The first thing to know about onDisconnect is that it triggers when the socket connection between Realtime Database and the client app is closed.  This could happen for any number of reasons, and it can happen at any time, even if the app seemingly has a good internet connection.  So, be careful about what you're trying to do here.

Also, onDisconnect triggers can only affect data in the database directly, and nothing else.  So, this limits what you can effectively accomplish.  You can't perform any action in the client app in response on an onDisconnect.

Between these two facts, what you're trying to do isn't really possible, *and*, I don't think it's desirable.  You could end up logging out the user just because their train went underground momentarily, or if they simply switched out of the application for some time.  This would be massively inconvenient to the user.

If you want to automatically log out the user, I strongly suggesting finding some other way to do this, such as writing some code to remember how long it's been since the user used your app, and forcing the logout on the on the client app based on your preferred logic.

Comment: Oh, thank you, this gives me pretty good insight on `.onDisconnect`. However, I am currently trying to implement a [user presence system](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/user-presenece-system-in-realtime/), and if the user closes the application without signing out, on reopening it, the sign-in page is automatically loaded. However, `this.afAuth.authState` still holds the session of that user, hence the `.subscribe` from the tutorial above is executed. Wouldn't this cause problems if the user logs into another account? What would be the correct way to handle the following situation?

Comment: A user can't be logged in twice to your app on the same device.  They'd have to log out of one and into the other.  Presence is not the same as auth.  Presence just says "I know you're here because you're connected", while auth says "I know who you are because you passed auth tests".  They are not really the same thing at all, and not really related, and I don't think it's wise to try to combine them.

Answer (score 2):

The `onDisconnect()` is related to the database connection, and has little to do with your authenticated user. As in: `onDisconnect()` may fire when your user is signed in, simply because the connection to the database drops temporarily.

But more importantly: `onDisconnect` handlers run server-side, once the server detects that the client has disappeared. When this is because if a dirty disconnect (e.g. the app crashes), there is no way for the client to detect this anymore.

The most likely approach you'll want is to simply sign the user out when they close the app.

Alternative you might want to attach a listener to `.info/connected` in your client. This is a client-side listener that fires when the *client* detects that it is connected or disconnected.